# Ms excel - how do I add 1 day to my custom date?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I'm trying to add days consecutively across row 9 starting with Sunday.
In field e3 is the date for the beginning of the pay period in 6/24/17 format
In field c9 I have =TEXT(E3,"ddd, m/dd")
In d9 I have tried 
  =TEXT(E3,"ddd, m/dd")+1
  =C9+1
And a few other ways but it returns "value"

How can I get the days in my custom format to auto grow in the custom format I have based on the original date in e3?

Comment: Just put the date into a field (formatted as date; don't use `TEXT` or your date will be a string), then in the next row just add 1 to it.  e,g, say A2 has `2017-06-24`, in A3 put `=A2+1`.

Comment: ps. Since this is for Excel, I'd suggest moving it to SuperUser rather than SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `TEXT` to format a date.  Rather, right click on the cell(s), select `Format Cells`, `Number`, `Custom`, and enter your custom format there.

To increment dates, simply doing `=dateCell + 1` works so long as that cell is a date; if it's not you're attempting to add 1 to a string; which doesn't make sense.

**Example**

Create a sheet with the following values/ formulae:

```
  | A           | B              |
1 | Date        | Formatted Date |
2 | 2017-06-24  | =A2            |
3 | =A2 + 1     | =B2 + 1        |
```

Leave column A's formatting as `General`; Excel will figure out that it's a date and will display it according to your local settings.

In column B, follow the steps above to format the cells as `ddd, M/dd`.

The result should look like this (column A's behaviour depending on your regional settings):

```
  | A           | B              |
1 | Date        | Formatted Date |
2 | 06/24/2017  | Wed, 6/24      |
3 | 06/25/2017  | Thu, 6/25      |
```